# Store content of next page after page navigation

Tags: perl, navigation, store, mechanize

I am using this code for page navigate a asp site.

```
$mech->click({xpath => '//li[@class="PagingNext"]', synchronize=>0, });
```

but i need help in saving the contents after the page navigation, that is store the next page contents in a variable. i am new to this. Need some help . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [CONTENT-HANDLING METHODS](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#CONTENT-HANDLING-METHODS):

```
my $content = $mech->content;
```

You probably want to find stuff in the HTML with [Web::Query](http://p3rl.org/Web%3a%3aQuery) or [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath) next.